# In what condition could ensure_future not actually start the future?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to asynchronously download a file in Python, using wget in a subprocess. My code looks like this:

```
async def download(url, filename):
    wget = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        'wget', url,
        'O', filename
    )
    await wget.wait()


def main(url):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(download(url, 'test.zip'), loop=loop)
    print("Downloading..")
    time.sleep(15)
    print("Still downloading...")
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
    loop.close()
```

What I'm trying to do is witness the printing of "Downloading.." then 15 seconds later "Still downloading...", all while the download of the file has started. What I'm actually seeing is that the download of the file only starts when the code hits loop.run_until_complete(future)

My understanding is that asyncio.ensure_future should start running the code of the `download` coroutine, but apparently I'm missing something.

Comment: That's because you added `time.sleep()`, which *prevents any coroutines from running*. Use cooperative sleep methods only, such as `asyncio.sleep()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When passed a coroutine, `asyncio.ensure_future` converts it to a task - a special kind of future that knows how to drive the coroutine - and enqueues it in the event loop. "Enqueue" means that the code inside the coroutine will be executed by a running event loop that schedules the coroutines. If the event loop is not running, then none of the coroutines will get a chance to run either. The loop is told to run by a call to `loop.run_forever()` or `loop.run_until_complete(some_future)`. In the question the event loop is only started *after* the call to `time.sleep()`, so the beginning of the download is delayed by 15 seconds.

`time.sleep` should **never** be called in a thread that runs the `asyncio` event loop. The correct way to sleep is with `asyncio.sleep`, which yields the control to the event loop while waiting. `asyncio.sleep` returns a future that can be submitted to the event loop or awaited from a coroutine:

```
# ... definition of download omitted ...

async def report():
    print("Downloading..")
    await asyncio.sleep(15)
    print("Still downloading...")

def main(url):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    dltask = loop.create_task(download(url, 'test.zip'))
    loop.create_task(report())
    loop.run_until_complete(dltask)
    loop.close()
```

The above code has a different problem. When the download is *shorter* than 15 seconds, it results in a `Task was destroyed but it is pending!` warning being printed. The problem is that the `report` task was never canceled when the download task finished and the loop closed, it was just abandoned. This happening often indicates a bug or a misunderstanding of how `asyncio` works, so `asyncio` flags it with a warning.

The obvious way to eliminate the warning is by explicitly canceling the task of the `report` coroutine, but the resulting code ends up being verbose and not very elegant. An simpler and shorter fix is to change `report` to await the download task, specifying a timeout for displaying the "Still downloading..." message:

```
async def dl_and_report(dltask):
    print("Downloading..")
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.shield(dltask), 15)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print("Still downloading...")
        # assuming we want the download to continue; otherwise
        # remove the shield(), and dltask will be canceled
        await dltask

def main(url):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    dltask = loop.create_task(download(url, 'test.zip'))
    loop.run_until_complete(dl_and_report(dltask))
    loop.close()
```

Comment: You can run asyncio.sleep with loop.run_until_complete; you don't actually need a coroutine to wrap it.

Comment: @SamHartman The coroutine is needed to ensure that the `print` executes after the sleep. Here the purpose of `sleep` is to print an indication after a timeout that the download is still in progress, and this would not be achieved with `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(15))`

Comment: As written, the answer implies that asyncio.sleep needs to be wrapped in a coroutine.  While wrapping it here is perhaps helpful, the answer would be better if it didn't imply that was a requirement

Comment: @SamHartman The important point is that you cannot just _call_ `asyncio.sleep` as an ordinary function, or nothing will happen. I've now amended the answer in a way that hopefully clarifies this.

Comment: Thanks for the edit; I've up-voted.  And I agree that not calling asyncio.sleep as a normal function is an important point.

Comment: @SamHartman No problem. By the way, if someone happens to know of a way to shut up the "Task was destroyed but it is pending!" warning without having to cancel the `report_task`, _and_ spin a useless `loop.run_until_complete(report_task)`, _and_ include a try/except in `report`, please advise. It seems unnecessarily verbose for the sole purpose of avoiding a warning, and I am thinking of asking a new SO question asking for a more elegant code.

Comment: ask that question and include a pointer here and I'll answer.  I don't see a question in a quick search.

Comment: @SamHartman I've now amended the answer with a variant that without either explicit canceling or the second `run_until_complete` call. It does require the report task to wrap the download task, but it still looks more elegant than the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

need to run the loop, after creating it

```
newloop=False
try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
except RuntimeError as e:
    if str(e).startswith('There is no current event loop in thread'):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        newloop=True
    else:
        raise
```

later in the code

```
if newloop:
    loop.run_forever()
```

-- the answer is for future googlers